# Why Http headers is being vanished when using ORJSONResponse() in fastAPI?

Tags: python, http-headers, fastapi, orjson

Http headers can be modified in [fastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/); however when I tried to use faster serializer (in this instance `ORJSONResponse`) in order to have faster response, all added or modified headers confusingly is being vanished. **I don't have any idea that why it happens and how can I fix it?**
also we got the same result for `UJSONResponse` too.

*thanks for sharing your experiences.*

#### A. This code can't modify headers

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Response
from fastapi.responses import ORJSONResponse
router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/test")
async def plan_list(response:Response):
    response.headers["test-header"]="test-value"
    return ORJSONResponse(list(range(10000)))
```

#### Output header list of code A:

```
date: Thu, 22 Oct 2020 18:42:19 GMT
server: uvicorn
content-length: 48891
content-type: application/json
```

#### B. This code modifies headers normally

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Response
from fastapi.responses import ORJSONResponse
router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/test")
async def plan_list(response:Response):
    response.headers["test-header"]="test-value"
    return list(range(10000))
```

#### Output header list of code B:

```
date: Thu, 22 Oct 2020 18:42:19 GMT
server: uvicorn
content-length: 48891
content-type: application/json
test-header: test-value
```

test platform:

- OS: macOS 10.15.7
- client: insomnia 2020.14.1
- python: 3.8.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2226) thanks to [amin jamal](https://github.com/includeamin).

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Response, FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import ORJSONResponse

app = FastAPI()
router = APIRouter()


@router.get("/test")
async def plan_list(response:Response):
       response.headers["test"]="test-value"
       return ORJSONResponse(list(range(10000)),headers=response.headers)



app.include_router(router)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Response like this

```
return Response(list(range(10000)))
```

Comment: unfortunately  its not correct answer  firstly `Response ` couldn't serialize json. secondly it causes the same effect and headers disappear too.

Comment: try
return JSONResponse(list(range(10000)))